How to navigate to a screen that previously built in flutter?
I have a series of APIs that are called on my home page and a series of widgets are created after receiving data from the server.
I want to shorten the loading time of these widgets, so I want my home page to be fully built while my splash screen is being shown, so that when the navigation operation happens, the audience will be faced with a ready page.
tested the following code, but apparently, until the HomeScreen widget is used in the build method, the build operation and calling the apis will not happen on the home page:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:imam/config/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:imam/core/utils/extensions.dart';
import 'package:imam/features/home/screens/home_screen.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  late HomeScreen homeScreen;

  @override
  void initState() {
    homeScreen =  HomeScreen();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      context.pushNamed(Routes.homeScreen);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Splash Screen',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

please pay attention that I don't want to wait for the load data of the home page, I just want all the components of the home page to be created at the same time in those 3 seconds when the splash page is shown.
And I don't want to use the Stack widget as a trick to solve this problem because the pages are supposed to be moved with navigation.
Thanks for your kindness.

Apparently, friends did not understand part of the question or maybe I
could not understand. I have no problem sending data to the home page,
my problem is that the home page widget itself is created on the
splash screen, and this is while the navigation to the home page has
not happened yet. I have a slider on my home page that even with ready
data takes almost 4 seconds to build!


You can use FutureProvider from Riverpod. Just call the provider in splash screen. Either wait for data to fetch and proceed or wait for 2-3 seconds and proceed to home page. Now as the future provider is already called, if you go to home page now, unless you update the future or use different provider, the data will be fetched already or will be in midway and will be fetched within 1 or half second if you didn't wait for it to complete in splash and just proceeded to Home page after 2-3 seconds. This is best way to handle even in case some error occurred or something unexpected happened.

Unfortunately i didn't work with Riverpod and current project is going on with Bloc.


please pay attention that I don't want to wait for the load data of
the home page

Then follow the approach that you exactly want! Since you mentioned that you don't want to wait for the data to load on the home screen, do not load it on the home screen.
Instead, one of the approaches you could follow is loading data on the splash screen, and then passing it to the home screen. The splash screen loads (asynchronously) the necessary data to be passed to the home screen, therefore navigate to the home screen and pass the loaded data.
Here is a high-level coding example:
Splash screen:
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadData();
  }

  Future<void> _loadData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

    final data = "Loaded Data";
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => HomeScreen(data: data),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

_loadData() should be the simulation of data loading. Therefore, you pass data to HomeScreen.
Next, Home Screen:
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;

  HomeScreen({required this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(data),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Keep in mind that in this case, the data-loading business logic will be a part of the splash screen; The Home screen receives data instead of loading it.

Additionally, as a quick workaround, you could check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70489180/5501940

In this case, if it takes more than 3 seconds to receive the data, the Home page will encounter incomplete data.
I have updated the question, please read the question again.

try using FutureBuilder in your SplashScreen,
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  SplashScreenState createState() => SplashScreenState();
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  late Future<void> _initializing;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializing = _initializingApp();
  }

  Future<void> _initializingApp() async {
    // Perform expensive operations, such as data fetching or widget pre-building
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    //Note: you can also fetch all the data, your HomeScreen() needs, in here and pass it to the HomeScreen()
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializing,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return const HomeScreen();
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          //handle errors here
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Splash Screen',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}


as i said "please pay attention that I don't want to wait for the load data of the home page"
